# php function to search paths for filename WITHOUT extension

Tags: php, string, file, preg-match

Right so i'm making a configuration class that will use an array of different file types in 4 main locations. Now I want to make it so that the configuration class will search these locations in order at the moment i'm using the following

```
if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . 'Application/Config/' . APP_ENV . DS . $file)) {
        $this->filePath = ROOT . DS . 'Application/Config/' . APP_ENV . DS . $file;
        echo $this->filePath;
    } else {
        if (file_exists(ROOT . DS . "Application/Config/$file")) {
            $this->filePath = ROOT . DS . "Application/Config/$file";
            echo $this->filePath;
        } else {
            if (file_exists(CARBON_PATH . 'Config' . DS . APP_ENV . DS . $file)) {
                $this->filePath = CARBON_PATH . 'Config' . DS . APP_ENV . DS . $file;
                echo $this->filePath;
            } else {
                if (file_exists(CARBON_PATH . "Config/$file")) {
                    $this->filePath = CARBON_PATH . "Config/$file";
                    echo $this->filePath;
                } else {
                    throw new \Exception("Unable to locate: $file, Please check it exists");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

pretty messy and not very flexible.

What I want to be able to do is search the locations in the same order BY FILE NAME ONLY after finding the first match It would then return the file with the extension for the configuration class to use the correct method to parse into a php array and so on.

What is the best way to search these locations for a file name

**Example**
Say we want a database configuration file as you can see there are 2

```
ConfigLocation1/Dev/
   /file.php
   /database.json
ConfigLocation1/
   /database.ini
   /anotherfile.json
```

I would want to use the function like so

```
config::findFile('database');
```

and it return

```
$result = ConfigLocation1/Dev/database.json
```

but if it wasnt found here then then

```
$result = ConfigLocation1/database.ini
```

Not very good at explaining things so hope the example helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you mentioned you need to check for file in 4 locations, so instead of if conditions, create an array of directories and loop through.

and you can use [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), to find a file irrespective of extension. see my example below:-

```
//Make a array of directory where you want to look for files.
$dirs = array(
    ROOT . DS . 'Application/Config/' . APP_ENV . DS,
    CARBON_PATH . 'Config' . DS . APP_ENV . DS
);

function findFiles($directory, $filename){
    $match = array();

    foreach ($directory => $dir) {
        $files = glob($dir.$filename);
        foreach ($files as $file) {
             $match[] = $file;
        }

    }

    return $match;
} 

// to find database
$results = findFiles($dirs, 'database.*');
```

Comment: Thank you for the **glob()**. Am I correct assuming this would return all results in an array ? How could I add a break within this so that it stops for the first item found as you would want a application file to be returned in preference to a core one

Comment: Yes, it will return array if results found, for further information see [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php), if you just need one occurrence just return match, break will look into next directory if directory array has

Comment: You don't need to test if a variable is empty before a foreach.